# Crop an image to use the cropped image as a background image on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, crop

I have a little problem and I know there have been questions about cropping images, but I haven't been able to find something that does the trick for me (like JCrop).

So, the menu on the left (where the background image is also visible) should only have that background image, the rest of it on the right should be cut away.

How do I only leave like, 55px of the left side of the pic and remove everything that I don't need?

Here's a link to the image that explains everything:
http://i283.photobucket.com/albums/kk294/erols/QUSTIONfw_zps25c32df5.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: really not clear what you are asking. If you want to actually crop an image do it using image library for your server language. If you want to only display part of an image, that would be done using css. Question needs a  lot more clarification.

Comment: I had made an image to show it, but I have to have a reputation of 10 in order to share the image that explains everything :([link](http://i283.photobucket.com/albums/kk294/erols/QUSTIONfw_zps25c32df5.png) I've put a link to the image in this comment :)

Comment: start with a concise explanation...if it's a display issue provide some html and enough css to represent issue

Comment: I've added an image to the original question with an image...

Comment: if content with background is over area that says `needs to be cut` won't see that part of image

Comment: So basically you have large images you use as backgrounds and you want only part of the image show as background?

Comment: Yes yuriy thats what i need